# Error while using Command line interface for Apex Dataloader 29.0

Tags: data-loader, commandline

While running encrypt .bat -g test on the command prompt.

I am getting following error :
2014-03-20 19:55:51,549 INFO  [main] security.EncryptionUtil main (EncryptionUti
l.java:289) - Invalid option format: .bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the bin directory just run encrypt -g test. Don't include the .bat bit.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I've tried with "run encrypt -g test" and with "run encrypt.bat -g test", but I continue getting the same error 289.

Comment: Ok, I re-wrote it by hand instead of copy-paste... and it worked!

Comment: You don't need the word 'run' in the command just "encrypt -g test"